# A result on extension fields in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a subfield of $E$,  $A$ an element of $\mathcal{M}_F(m,n)$ and $b$ a vector in $F^m \subset E^m$.

What is the easiest way to prove the following statement:
 *if $Ax = b$ has a solution in $E^n$ then it has a solution in the subset $F^n$.*

Comment: You should have $b\in F^m\subset E^m$ :)

Comment: I was being consistent with the fact that I have written $A$ is an element of ... before that statement.

Comment: No, you weren't!! $A\in \mathcal M_F(m,n)$ represents a linear map from $F^n$ to $F^m$. The solution $x$ lives in $F^n$, but the element $b$ in the image lives in $F^m$ !!

Comment: Oh sorry. I misread your comment. I thought you were talking about the notation here (writing "$a \in A \subset B$" instead of "$a$ is an element of $A \subset B$"). Editing it now. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

One may determine whether $Ax=b$ has a solution by using row operations. Since $A$ and $b$ have entries in $F$, this process is defined completely over $F$, without reference to the field $E$.

Comment: Don't we have row multiplication as one of the row operations? Wouldn't that refer to the field $E$?

Comment: Yes there is row multiplication, but you only ever need to multiply/divide by elements of $F$ since the coefficients of $A$ are in $F$.

Comment: E.g. if $\alpha \neq 0$ is the value of a entry $ij$ in $A$, then by dividing the $i$th row by $\alpha$ gives a 1 in the $ij$th entry. This is okay since $\alpha$ was already in $F$. Since $F$ is closed under addition/multiplication, we never introduce entries which are not in $F$ by doing row operations.

Comment: True. This is quite neat :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $Ax=b$ has a solution in $E^n$ tells you that the row rank of the augmented matrix $[A|b]$ is equal to the row rank of the matrix $A$, working with scalars in $E$. What you need to check (and it does follow from uniqueness of reduced echelon form, for example) is that $v_1,\dots, v_m\in F^n$ are linearly independent over $E$ if and only if they are linearly independent over $F$. So row rank working over $E$ is equal to row rank working over $F$.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea too but what do you think would be easiest way to prove that last statement? I know one way would be to use the characterisation of matrix rank using determinants (rank $r$ of $A$ is the largest integer $r$ for which there is an $r \times r$ non-zero minor). Can you think of solution which doesn't involve the determinants?

Comment: You don't need determinants. You reduce the problem to showing that $Cx=0$ has only the trivial solution for $x\in F^n$ only if $Cx=0$ has only the trivial solution for $x\in E^n$. The point is that the condition that you have a pivot in every column of the echelon form of $C$ is independent of whether we work over $E$ or over $F$, since the reduced echelon form will be unique.

Comment: Yes, this is in the same spirit as the answer by Dane.